# Machine learning Random forests

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to fit a random forest classifier on an imbalanced dataset using the scikit-learn Python library.

My goal is to obtain more or less the same value for recall and precision, and to do so, I am using the class_weight parameter of the RandomForestClassifier function.

When fitting the Random Forest with a class_weight = {0:1, 1:1}, (in other words, assuming the dataset is not imbalanced), I obtain:

Accuracy: 0.79
Precision: 0.63
Recall: 0.32
AUC: 0.74

When I change the class_weight to {0:1, 1:10}, I obtain:

Accuracy: 0.79
Precision: 0.65
Recall: 0.29
AUC: 0.74

So, the recall and precision values almost have not changed (even if I increase from 10 to 100, the changes are minimal).

Since the X_train and X_test are both imbalanced in the same proportions (the dataset has more than 1 million rows), shouldn't I obtain very different recall and precision values when using the class_weight = {0:1, 1:10}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increase the recall of your model there is a much faster way of doing so.

You can compute the [precision recall curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve) using sklearn.

This curve will give you the trade-off between precision and recall for your model.

This means, if you want to increase your recall of your model, you could ask the random forest to retrieve you the probabilities for each class, add 0.1 to class 1 and subtract 0.1 to the probability of class 0. This will effectively increase your recall

If you plot the precision recall curve you will be able to find the optimal threshold for equal precision and recall

Here you have the example from sklearn

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Add noisy features
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

# Limit to the two first classes, and split into training and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X[y < 2], y[y < 2],
                                                    test_size=.5,
                                                    random_state=random_state)

# Create a simple classifier
classifier = svm.LinearSVC(random_state=random_state)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_score = classifier.decision_function(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.utils.fixes import signature

precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_score)

# In matplotlib < 1.5, plt.fill_between does not have a 'step' argument
step_kwargs = ({'step': 'post'}
               if 'step' in signature(plt.fill_between).parameters
               else {})
plt.step(recall, precision, color='b', alpha=0.2,
         where='post')
plt.fill_between(recall, precision, alpha=0.2, color='b', **step_kwargs)

plt.xlabel('Recall')
plt.ylabel('Precision')
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
```

Which should give you something like [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/sphx_glr_plot_precision_recall_001.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I also know that exists this possibility. However, isn't it a bit strange that the recall and precision almost do not alter with such different class_weights?

Comment: maybe your test data is quite different from the training data. That could explain this kind of behaviour

Comment: Both y_train and y_test have a mean around 0.24. I also tried other models like LightGBM and MLP using keras, and in both approaches changing the class_weight was sufficient.

Comment: Tree based methods are forced to use features as they are and they do not use linear or non linear combinations of them. So maybe good answer to your problem requires using combinations of features and the model doesn't. while MLP does

Comment: If you want to test for this hypothesis, you can try to learn your classifier using PolinomialFeatures as input to your classifier and check if something changes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Really appreciate it. The strange thing though, is that the LightGBM model reacted perfectly when changing the scale_pos_weight parameter. As opposed to what is happening now with Random Forests

Comment: There is a final possibility. That the model is overfitting and predicting classes with high confidence (probas either close to 1 or 0) even if it is wrong.

Comment: That was it! When I constrained the max_depth parameter to a low number, I then observed a huge change in the recall metric. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary answer, you can also try to optimize your model towards one or more metrics. You can use [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) to look for a good combination of hyperparameters for you. For instance, if you training a Random Forest classifier":

```
#model
MOD = RandomForestClassifier() 
#Implemente RandomSearchCV
m_params = { 
            "RF": {
                    "n_estimators" : np.linspace(2, 500, 500, dtype = "int"),  
                    "max_depth": [5, 20, 30, None], 
                    "min_samples_split": np.linspace(2, 50, 50, dtype = "int"),  
                    "max_features": ["sqrt", "log2",10, 20, None],
                    "oob_score": [True],
                    "bootstrap": [True]
                    },
            }
    scoreFunction = {"recall": "recall", "precision": "precision"}
    random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(MOD,
                                       param_distributions = m_params[model], 
                                       n_iter = 20,
                                       scoring = scoreFunction,               
                                       refit = "recall",
                                       return_train_score = True,
                                       random_state = 42,
                                       cv = 5,
                                        verbose = 1 + int(log)) 

    #trains and optimizes the model
    random_search.fit(x_train, y_train)

    #recover the best model
    MOD = random_search.best_estimator_
```

Note that the parameters scoring and refit will tell the RandomizedSerachCV which metrics you are most interested in maximizing. This method will also save you the time of hand tuning (and potentially overfitting your model on your test data).

Good luck!